# Standard JavaScript regular expressions to match from tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to pull below 3 values from tag of dynatrace with regex and tried :

```
} else {
    //Regex to find CFU, Environment & Snowappid from tags
    var add_info_parser = JSON.parse(requestBody);
    var regex_match = new RegExp(/^(?=.*Environment:\s*(\w+))(?=.*CFU:\s*(\w+))(?=.*SnowAppID:\s*(\w+)).*/igm);
    var tags = add_info_parser.Tags;
    gs.info("Dynatarce before regex match" + tags);
    regex_match = regex_match.exec(tags);
    gs.info("Dynatrace regex value" + regex_match);
    appIdTag = regex_match[3].toString();
    environmentTag = regex_match[1].toString();
    var CFU_value = regex_match[2].toString().toLowerCase();
    if (cfuOverride.indexOf(CFU_value) > -1) {
        overrideBinding = true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it has not worked.

Can anybody help with Standard JavaScript regular expressions to match from below tags:

1. SnowAppID:**APP12130**
2. Environment: **PROD**
3. CFU: **Consumer**

From this line. I need to use push connector which run on javascript.

"EnterpriseCloud, Environment:PROD, Data Centre:London, ServiceNow-Integrated:True, CFU:Consumer, SnowAppID:APP12130, Application:KCIM"

Comment: You have to take the spaces into account `^(?=.*Environment:\s*(\w+))(?=.*CFU:\s*(\w+))(?=.*SnowAppID:\s*(\w+)).*` See https://regex101.com/r/ZpcFd3/1

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for quick response, I am trying to use for push connector. Could you please help me with small piece of code which i can insert .. Its for Servicenow and javascrip

Comment: I have no knowledge about push connector. In that case I would advise to update your question with the relevant code that you are trying so that other volunteers can better assist you.

Comment: Thank, sure. i will update the tags. Also, what's wrong with below. Its adding , and 4 groups:   ^(?=.*CFU:\s*([^\],|"]+))(?=.*Environment:\s*([^\],|"]+))(?=.*SnowAppID:\s*([^\],|"]+))

Comment: What are you trying to match with `[^],|"]+` ? https://regex101.com/r/qpl9Y3/1

Comment: Please provide an an example of input and expected output. Be more specific than "it has not worked", what is happening that shouldn't, what isn't happening that should, are you getting any console errors?